# Asynchronous Callbacks with different threadIDs == Multithreaded?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, callback

I run example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) 
and I am not shutting down and closing sockets in SendCallback (i am keeping my connection with clients). And i put this in ReadCallback:

`Console.WriteLine("ManagedThreadID:"+Thread.CurrentThread.Ma‌​nagedThreadId.ToStri‌​ng());`

Then i spam messages with my client and server shows me different ThreadIDs, and I read here on stackoverflow in many topics that asynchronous callbacks aren't multithreaded.
If its not multithreaded why it generates different threadIDS then? If its single thread it should do in with the same threadID?

[image]Picture attached threadids ran from 11 to 17.

Comment: Different threads (from thread pool) process the client calls but it is not multithreading in terms of parallelism, as only one thread can process the client call at the same time

Comment: Back in the old days before `async/await`, you typically implement `IAsyncResult` sources using the thread pool, hence the different thread IDs for each `Beginxxx()` session

Comment: @tomassino Who said anything about parallelism?